# Caching regions in Oracle APEX which are updated via Dynamic actions

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle

I have tried to enable caching for a region (interactive report).  The region is updated whenever any of 3 page items are updated - which are used to drive filters in the underlying SQL.  These items which have dynamic actions on them are:

```
P1_REGION
P1_STATUS
P1_PRODUCT
```

The dynamic actions simply send the new value back to session state and refresh the region.

The report reqion is just drive by SQL:

```
select * 
from T_CASES
where region = :P1_REGION and status =:P1_STATUS and product = :P1_PRODUCT
```

I have set the caching to be "by session"  on the report region, timeout in 30 minutes and have added these 3 page items as dependencies on the cache.

But whenever I change one of the page items, the report just clears.

How do I enable caching on a region, which is updated via dynamic actions on a report driven by SQL which uses page item bind variables?

Comment: What page number is the interactive report on? After it refreshes what values do you find for those 3 items in session state?

Comment: They are all on page 1 (updated question, I misnamed something as P2)....all page items are being posted back to session correctly, just the region empties rather than invalidate the cache and reload.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to inspect here is what values are in session state after the report is refreshed. If P1_REGION, P2_STATUS, and P1_PRODUCT are not being sent to the server on the change then the report query will see them as null and give an empty result.

Look underneath the SQL source of the report for the property Page Items to Submit and make sure these three items are in there.

Comment: Each dynamic action , on each page item, is independently posting its own value back into to session state via a PLSQL expression.  The values are getting posted correctly in session state

Comment: I have no easy answers. You can run debug mode and see what occurs when the report refreshes. You can turn off cache in the region and compare.

I made a simple test of an interactive report with one filtered page item, turned on caching dependent on that item and created a refresh action. In my testing the cache only works when the page is refreshed but not when the report is refreshed.

Comment: You also said that each item posts its value back via PL/SQL. Common way to do this is to add those items to the Source attributes of the report in the Page Items to Submit. Using PL/SQL means you may run into asynch issues.

Comment: The refresh action of the region in the dynamic action is always after the submission to session via PL\SQL of the page items?

Comment: Is this a question or statement? Any dynamic action action that is to execute pl/sql can occur asynchronously so your refresh may happen after the call but may not happen after the call has completed. Adding the property Page Items to Submit to the report source keeps this problem away.

Comment: If I have one dynamic action, with 4 TRUE actions in it, and the first action is an Execute PL\SQL statement, which sends values to session, adjusts them and returns a value, and then there are 3 actions after the Execute PL\SQL action....I am assuming that all actions within the one DA are fired synchronously one after the other.  I get DIFFERENT DAs may be firing asynchronously - but if I define 4 actions in a single DA, I expect them to run top to bottom, or it makes a mockery of the SEQUENCE number

Comment: Unless you turn on the Wait for ... property they execute async. I order yes, but your refresh may happen before the plsql completes. At any rate you can turn on debug and figure out what your query is doing on the refresh. If it returns no rows my hunch is you have a null somewhere

Comment: Wait for result is the default, thanks for the reminder though

Comment: Not sure how to help more. Turn on debug. Test. Look for values being set in session state. Turn off Region Cache and repeat and compare. Post more info here if none of this clarifies the source of the problem.